# Why is my code returning value of 'null' from a nested JSON array

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-volley

So I'm trying to get the 'statusSeveretyDescription' which is inside 'lineStatus'.  The first 'for' loop works, however, the nested loop returns null..  A pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.   Please see code and an image of the JSON below.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject object = array.optJSONObject(i);
    String line = object.optString("id");

    //nested array
    JSONArray arrayStatus = object.getJSONArray("lineStatuses");
    int len = arrayStatus.length();

    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {                                
        JSONObject o = arrayStatus.getJSONObject(j);
        String statusSeverityDescription = o.optString(
                                            "statusSeverityDescription", "");
    }

    if (line != null) {
        tubeLines.add(line  + statusSeverityDescription);
    }

    // Once we added the string to the array, we notify the arrayAdapter
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues.

1) Your variable scoping is incorrect, your `statusSeverityDescription` variable is being deallocated as soon as the for loop ends. To fix this, move `String statusSeverityDescription` outside of the for loop, like so

```
String statusSeverityDescription;
for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {                                
   JSONObject o = arrayStatus.getJSONObject(j);
   statusSeverityDescription = o.optString(
                                        "statusSeverityDescription", "");
}
```

2) `statusSeverityDescription` should be an array which store all the `statusSeverityDescription`'s in your json payload. So make it an array, or understand that the last processed `statusSeverityDescription` for a given `lineStatuses` will be the `statusSeverityDescription` you're left with.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation was most helpful. Cheers, Aaron.